# Passing an foreachable array from C# to PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

How can I pass an array from C# to PowerShell that can be `foreach`ed?

Right now I have this script:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Numbers")]
public class GetNumbersCmdlet: Cmdlet
{
    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("1");
        list.Add("2");
        list.Add("3");
        list.Add("4");
        list.Add("5");
        WriteObject(results.ToArray());
    }
}
```

And this PowerShell script:

```
foreach ($number in Get-Numbers) {
    Write-Output "Output is $number"
}
```

Instead of:

```
Output is 1
Output is 2
Output is 3
Output is 4
Output is 5
```

I would get:

```
Output is 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: So if I pull out `Get-Numbers` and assign the results to a variable first then `foreach` that variable, everything works as intended. I've filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4813).

Comment: `WriteObject(results.ToArray(), true);`

Comment: @PetSerAl Could you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell do not automatically enumerate output of commands. That means if command write collection into pipeline, then that collection will be passed to the next command as single object.

`WriteObject` also do not enumerate objects unless explicitly asked.

So to solve your problem, you can write objects as you go instead of collecting them:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Numbers")]
public class GetNumbersCmdlet: Cmdlet
{
    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        WriteObject("1");
        WriteObject("2");
        WriteObject("3");
        WriteObject("4");
        WriteObject("5");
    }
}
```

Or you can ask `WriteObject` to enumerate your collection:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Numbers")]
public class GetNumbersCmdlet: Cmdlet
{
    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("1");
        list.Add("2");
        list.Add("3");
        list.Add("4");
        list.Add("5");
        WriteObject(results, true);
    }
}
```

Note that in both cases you are not writing array anymore, but individual items of it.